# Type Error in CiviEventDispatcher.php on line 263

Tags: wordpress, symfony

I do not generally work on WordPress but I am trying to help a friend.  I have a WordPress 6.4.2 site with CiviCRM 5.69.2 and PHP 8.2.3.

Since upgrading PHP when trying to bootstrap the site I get the following error:

```
TypeError thrown with message "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher::dispatch(): Argument #2 ($event) must be of type ?Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event, string given, called in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php on line 263"
```

This sname error was discussed in relation to Drupal 10 with https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2316. A PR was created and appears to be merged https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19960 but I am still having this problem.

I am running this instance of the site using ddev on my local computer.

Any help on how to approach this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a stack trace? There might be an extension or wordpress plugin that bundles an older version of symfony and so there are two conflicting versions.